# How to reapply Zend Framework nature to a netbeans project?

Tags: php, netbeans, zend

I'm working on a netbeans project with a Zend Framework "nature" on two computer synced by mercurial.
On the first computer, where the project has been created, project is marked as a ZF one and I can run ZF.bat commands in contextual menu.

On the second one, project has been imported via mercurial but ZF nature is not applied to project.

I checked config files but found nothing related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it.

Netbeans uses the file named .zfproject.xml (created by Zend_Tool) to apply ZF nature to its projects.

This file wasn't synced in my repo so the second computer thought it was a standalone PHP project.